# the difference between "come of" and "come from"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. He **came of** a rich family.
> 2. He **came from** a rich family.

Which is correct?  *came of* or *came from*? Explain to me.

Answer (score 1):

Among their definitions of "come of," some dictionaries, such as [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/come+of), include

> to be descended from

This would indicate that the term is synonymous with "come from," and that either may be used as you have in your example.

Many other dictionaries, however, do not include this definition (such as macmillandictionary.com and merriam-webster.com), probably because, generally speaking, in colloquial English, "come of" is not used to mean "descended from." It more often means "to result from," as in

> Nothing came of his efforts.

It is also used in the idiom

> to come of age

which means to reach the age of maturity.

Generally speaking, you will often hear *He came from a rich family,* and rarely, if ever, hear *He came of a rich family*.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "He came from a rich family." Native English speakers would never say "came of." We might, in some stretch of imagination, say that "he came out of a rich family," but this is not likely.